# How To Uninstall ProtonVPN

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I installed ProtonVPN from the proton site. I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove the remaining pieces of the software. I've done the usual things:

1. Checked the ubuntu Store (not there)
2. Purged protonvpn (can't find)
3. apt remove protonvpn (can't find)
4. unhid files and searched in Files and deleted all the protonvpn remnants I could find.

Yet, I can still launch ProtonVPN from the desktop icon/application launcher

Any thoughts?

Comment: How you remove software depends upon how you installed it. Your description "*from the proton site*" is too vague to offer advice. Please edit your question to clearly explain how you installed the software. More details are better.

Comment: The website has updated instructions to remove the official Linux app:
sudo apt autoremove proton-vpn-gnome-desktop && sudo apt purge protonvpn-stable-release
Source: https://protonvpn.com/support/official-ubuntu-vpn-setup/

Answer (score 5):

You downloaded a deb file. So it can't be in the store.

Proton describes it very [clearly](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/):

> sudo apt-get install protonvpn

Later in the "notes" they write:

To uninstall the official app:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove protonvpn
#Remove any leftover files: 
rm -rf ~/.cache/protonvpn 
rm -rf ~/.config/protonvpn
```

Seems to be pretty straight forward. (RTFM)

Comment: they should write better software that follows standard uninstall

Comment: this leaves a problem with insecure 'https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable Release'
> no longer has a Release file
https://askubuntu.com/a/310/421929

Comment: By the time I found this post, I had alredy followed the uninstall instructions from the protonvpn website but ended up getting an error whenever I ran "sudo apt-get update" stating signatures could not be verified for the protonvpn repo. I tried checking the Ubuntu Software & Update center to remove the repo but it wasn't there... Yet I still got the error. I found the repo at "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/protonvpn-stable.list". I removed that file and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This last answer from iceMonkee helped me. I did have to CHOWN permissions in that folder but is gone now. And I echo the sentiments of prismspecs